# Apple Pay on Web - Merchant identificator certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, applepay, adyen

Hello fellow Stackers,

I am trying to implement Apple Pay on Web in our eCommerce.

I am just dealing with Merchant Identification Certificate problem.

We are using PHP 5.6 and curl to call Apple Pay validation to get ApplePaySession from Apple sessions.

I created a certificate in Apple Developer console, I downloaded and added that certificate into Keychain. Exported .p12 file and created two files:
cert.pem with a certificate and key.pem with private key by these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in applePayCert.p12 -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys

openssl pkcs12 -in applePayCert.p12 -out key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

I am calling Apple Servers by curl

```
$data = json_encode([
    'merchantIdentifier' => ADYENAPPLEPAY_APPLE_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER,
    'initiativeContext'  => PRODUCTION_DOMAINNAME,
    'displayName'        => ADYENAPPLEPAY_APPLE_DISPLAY_NAME,
    'initiative'         => 'web',
]);

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $validationUrlFromApplePayJs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, PRODUCTION_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, PRODUCTION_CERTIFICATE_KEY);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I call

```
curl_error($ch)
```

I got

> unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

But I didn't set any password

Comment: Okay, problem is solved. I used Guzzle to make request. So it was ssome problem with CURL

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on how you formatted your Guzzle request? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @JakubStejskal can you provide final version of your Guzzle request which solved you issue?